# Why does this function throw munmap_chunck() in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, runtime-error

I wrote a function, which traverses a graph to find an euler tour. I have a vector `tour`, that stores the final tour. If I initialize it with the starting vertex `0`, then I get a `munmap_chuck(): invalid pointer` error after calling depth first search the first time. If I don't initialze it, the error is not thrown. But the `dfs_tour()` function doesn't change anything at `tour`, and it is also not changed anywhere else until then. The initialization is necessary to make the function work in the end.

So why does this happen?

The `graph` is a multigraph represented with a two dimensional map `vertex1 --> vertex2 --> number of edges between them`. It is unweighted.

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

typedef map<int, map<int, int>> map_2d;
void dfs_tour(int start, map_2d &graph, vector<int> &subtour);
void remove_edge(map_2d &graph, int v1, int v2);
vector<int> euler_tour(map_2d &graph);

int main() {
    map_2d graph;

    graph[0][1] = 1;
    graph[0][3] = 2;
    graph[0][5] = 1;
    graph[1][2] = 1;
    graph[1][6] = 2;
    graph[2][3] = 1;
    graph[3][4] = 1;
    graph[4][5] = 1;

    euler_tour(graph);
}

vector<int> euler_tour(map_2d &graph) {
    // If this is not initialized, the error is not thrown.
    vector<int> tour{ 0 };
    vector<int> subtour;

    int start = 0;
    while (!graph.empty()) {
        // The error is thrown here after the function return in the first iteration.
        cout << "before dfs\n";
        dfs_tour(start, graph, subtour); 
        cout << "after dfs\n";

        if (graph[start].empty()) {
            graph.erase(start);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < tour.size(); i++) {
            if (tour[i] == start) {
                tour.insert(tour.begin() + i, subtour.begin(), subtour.end());
                break;
            }
        }

        for (auto it = graph.begin(); it != graph.end(); it++) {
            if (!it->second.empty()) {
                start = it->first; break;
            }
        }
        subtour.clear();
    }
    return tour;
}

// Auxiliary Functions

void remove_edge(map_2d &graph, int v1, int v2) {
    graph.at(v1).at(v2) -= 1;
    graph.at(v2).at(v1) -= 1;

    if (graph.at(v1).at(v2) == 0) {
        graph.at(v1).erase(v2);
        graph.at(v2).erase(v1);
    }

    if (graph.at(v1).empty()) {
        graph.erase(v1);
    }

    if (graph.at(v2).empty()) {
        graph.erase(v2);
    }
}

void dfs_tour(int start, map_2d &graph, vector<int> &subtour) {
    if (!graph[start].empty()){
        int next = graph[start].begin()->first;
        cout << start << " to " << next << endl;
        remove_edge(graph, start, next);
        dfs_tour(next, graph, subtour);
    }
    subtour.push_back(start);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? Also, step through the code with a debugger! There are video tutorials out there which are probably the easiest way to learn.

Comment: Does this help? I think you should be able to run it yourself now. I debugged it line by line, it breaks when the first call of `dfs()` returns. If i do not initialize `tour` with a value, it does not break. I also tried different methods of initialization.

Comment: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9e697e7954bfd3ae. `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'; what():  map::at`. There's one function using `map::at()`, so take a closer look at that.